# Responsive Video Container -> no width/height issue

Tags: css, responsive

I have a stylesheet for responsive youtube video embeds like that:

```
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
  padding-top: 30px; 
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

This works like a charm.
Now I have this wrapped into divs with the following classes like this:

```
.blog-wrapper > .blog-row > .blog-column
```

When I use the `.video-container` class within the `.blog-column` it doesn't work anymore but gets the dimensions of 0 x 30.
When I place the `.video-container` in `.blog-row` or `.blog-wrapper` it works again, but this obviously doesn't fit with the layout.

How can I make the `.video-container` work within `.blog-column` without changing:

```
.blog-wrapper .blog-row .blog-column
```

because changes there would affect the rest of the page as well.

Some more CSS:

```
.blog-column {
  max-width: 590px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 15px 0;
}
```

I didn't find any css for .blog-wrapper and .blog-row, these only contain css for elements within the classes so I didn't include them here.

Some HTML to reproduce:

```
<div class="blog-row">
<div class="blog-column">
<p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
<p class="description" style="text-align: justify;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut 
labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et 
accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea 
takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut 
labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et 
accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea 
takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
</p>
<p class="link"><a href="some dead link">this is a dead link</a></p>
</div>
<div class="blog-column">
<div class="video-container"><iframe frameborder="0" height="315" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/z8Zj7aVrt4M?ecver=1" width="560"> 
</iframe></div>
</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cLmoa58o/

Comment: Could it be you are missing the dot before the class names?

Comment: Where do you mean? I have them in the declarations like above, I didn't include them in my text and I don't use them in the html part, I use the classes like this:`<div class="video-container"><iframe frameborder="0" height="315" src="some youtube link" width="560"></iframe></div>`

Comment: Your example is without the dot: `blog-wrapper > blog-row > blog-column`

Comment: ok i added those to have this clean.
But that's not the problem because in the declarations all the dots are there and all the classes work, only the combination of `.video-container` doesn't work within the `.blog-column`

Comment: We need more to duplicate the problem: [mcve]

Comment: Do you have anywhere in the css where you use box-sizing:border-box; If you do then the video-container height: 0; is going to ignore your padding

Comment: @Rob: I am working on a better example.

Comment: I guess this should be it: https://jsfiddle.net/cLmoa58o/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the `width: 100%` to your `.blog-column` :)
Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y2q9L125/